# Why is `site-packages` placed at the end of my Python search path when I `conda activate`?

Tags: conda, virtualenv, miniconda

I'm experiencing an import failure, which I believe is due to my import "stack" taking a slight detour away from my `minconda3` virtual environment and into my *system* Python installation:

Traceback of failed `PIL.Image` import

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\capnf\miniconda3\envs\pybert-tst\lib\site-packages\enable\qt4\base_window.py", line 255, in paintEvent
    self.handler.paintEvent(event)
  File "C:\Users\capnf\miniconda3\envs\pybert-tst\lib\site-packages\enable\qt4\base_window.py", line 90, in paintEvent
    self._enable_window._paint(event)
  File "C:\Users\capnf\miniconda3\envs\pybert-tst\lib\site-packages\enable\abstract_window.py", line 536, in _paint
    self.component.draw(gc, view_bounds=(0, 0, size[0], size[1]))
  File "C:\Users\capnf\miniconda3\envs\pybert-tst\lib\site-packages\enable\component.py", line 410, in draw
    self._draw(gc, view_bounds, mode)
  File "C:\Users\capnf\miniconda3\envs\pybert-tst\lib\site-packages\enable\component.py", line 791, in _draw
    self._dispatch_draw(layer, gc, view_bounds, mode)
  File "C:\Users\capnf\miniconda3\envs\pybert-tst\lib\site-packages\enable\container.py", line 270, in _dispatch_draw
    component._dispatch_draw(layer, gc, new_bounds, mode)
  File "C:\Users\capnf\miniconda3\envs\pybert-tst\lib\site-packages\enable\container.py", line 270, in _dispatch_draw
    component._dispatch_draw(layer, gc, new_bounds, mode)
  File "C:\Users\capnf\miniconda3\envs\pybert-tst\lib\site-packages\enable\component.py", line 809, in _dispatch_draw
    handler(gc, view_bounds, mode)
  File "C:\Users\capnf\miniconda3\envs\pybert-tst\lib\site-packages\chaco\base_2d_plot.py", line 221, in _draw_image
    self._render(gc)
  File "C:\Users\capnf\miniconda3\envs\pybert-tst\lib\site-packages\chaco\plots\cmap_image_plot.py", line 101, in _render
    ImagePlot._render(self, gc)
  File "C:\Users\capnf\miniconda3\envs\pybert-tst\lib\site-packages\chaco\plots\image_plot.py", line 165, in _render
    gc.draw_image(self._cached_image, self._cached_dest_rect)
  File "C:\Users\capnf\miniconda3\envs\pybert-tst\lib\site-packages\kiva\agg\agg.py", line 1216, in draw_image
    from PIL import Image
  File "C:\Users\capnf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\capnf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\capnf\miniconda3\envs\pybert-tst\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 100, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
  File "C:\Users\capnf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\capnf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: The specified module could not be found.
```

In troubleshooting this, I find that my *system* Python installation's `site-packages/` folder appears *before* that of my `conda` virtual environment, despite the fact that all other paths related to my virtual environment appear before my system path entry!:

```
(base)
capnf@DESKTOP-G84ND7C MINGW64 ~
$ conda activate pybert-tst

(pybert-tst)
capnf@DESKTOP-G84ND7C MINGW64 ~
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
[ ''
, 'C:\\Users\\capnf\\miniconda3\\envs\\pybert-tst\\python39.zip'
, 'C:\\Users\\capnf\\miniconda3\\envs\\pybert-tst\\DLLs'
, 'C:\\Users\\capnf\\miniconda3\\envs\\pybert-tst\\lib'
, 'C:\\Users\\capnf\\miniconda3\\envs\\pybert-tst'
, 'C:\\Users\\capnf\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages'
, 'C:\\Users\\capnf\\miniconda3\\envs\\pybert-tst\\lib\\site-packages'
]
```

**What is the reason for doing it this way?**

### System Info:

- Windows 11 Home
- Miniconda3:

  - Python 3.9
  - `conda` v23.1.0

### Follow-on Sleuthing Results

Aha! After completely removing my `AppData/Roaming/Python/` folder, the offending entry in my Python search path is now absent upon reactivating my `pybert-tst` virtual environment:

```
(base)
capnf@DESKTOP-G84ND7C MINGW64 ~
$ conda activate pybert-tst

(pybert-tst)
capnf@DESKTOP-G84ND7C MINGW64 ~
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
[ ''
, 'C:\\Users\\capnf\\miniconda3\\envs\\pybert-tst\\python39.zip'
, 'C:\\Users\\capnf\\miniconda3\\envs\\pybert-tst\\DLLs'
, 'C:\\Users\\capnf\\miniconda3\\envs\\pybert-tst\\lib'
, 'C:\\Users\\capnf\\miniconda3\\envs\\pybert-tst'
, 'C:\\Users\\capnf\\miniconda3\\envs\\pybert-tst\\lib\\site-packages'
]
```

So, maybe, the construction of the new Python search path upon activation of a `conda` virtual environment is performed dynamically and programmatically, as opposed to just being an amalgam of certain static entities (i.e. - environment variables, etc.)?

**If so, where is this assemblage performed?**